# a=( one two three ) -- why does for x in $a only loop over "one"?

Tags: linux, bash

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "usage: ./test.sh [one|two|three|four|five]"
    exit
elif [ $# -eq 1 -a $1 = "all" ]; then
    params=("one" "two" "three" "four" "five")
else
    params=$@
fi

echo "=========="

for param in $params
do
    if [ $param = "one" ]; then
        echo "one"
    elif [ $param = "two" ]; then
        echo "two"
    elif [ $param = "three" ]; then
        echo "three"
    elif [ $param = "four" ]; then
        echo "four"
    elif [ $param = "five" ]; then
        echo "five"
    fi
    echo "=========="
done
```

if I try `./test.sh one` or `./test.sh two` ecc it work, but when I try `./test.sh all`it not work and print only one.

Where is the problem???
Thanks
Dario

Comment: Thanks :D now it works

Comment: @yellowantphil, the original syntax was correct for an array, just the OP was expanding it wrong. `for param in "${params[@]}"` is correct. The change you made, using a single string rather than a proper array, is **far** much less flexible: You can't have, say, `params=( "first item" "second item" "third item" )` that way.

Comment: Bash arrays: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays . Or see the documentation https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays but the first guide is probably a better tutorial.

Comment: @yellowantphil, that only works if you can't have newline literals. Newline literals happen -- sometimes, with my security hat on, newline literals can happen *intentionally* as part of an attack.

Comment: @yellowantphil, I'll keep that in mind if I want to make one of your scripts delete `/etc/passwd`, and try creating content like `/tmp/ $'\n'/etc/passwd`. Or to simply create non-deletable content, or any other manner of mischief.

Comment: @yellowantphil, if you're making it easy for someone who can create files as `nobody` to escalate that attack, then you're... well... making it easy. :)

Comment: @yellowantphil, ...similarly, there are often web services or such that honor filenames given by the client, even if only inside a limited directory space... though the biggest data loss I've seen professionally (of multiple TB of logs used for billing) was caused by a buffer overflow, and a completely incidental (not intentional exploit) event creating a filename containing a whitespace-surrounded wildcard character in a directory that folks had assumed "couldn't possibly" have files that didn't match `[0-9a-f]{24}`.

Comment: @yellowantphil, ...my point, there, being that the people writing that code *didn't think* they had to handle any nontrivial cases. If you wait until you **know** that you need to handle a corner case to actually do the right thing, it may be too late.

Comment: In general, pasting every script you write in http://www.shellcheck.net/ is a good way to learn to avoid bad syntax. *bash* is tricky...

Answer (score 4):

```
for param in $params
```

...is the wrong way to expand an array. Instead, use:

```
params=( "$@" )
for param in "${params[@]}"
```

---

To explain **why** array syntax is better, consider the following:

```
params=( "first item" "second item" "third item" )
for param in "${params[@]}"; do
  echo "$param"
done
```

...you can't do that (keeping your words together) with the string syntax.

Comment: This doesn't work with `param=$@` (I guess you can use `param=( "$@" )`?)

Comment: @TomFenech, correct, `param=( "$@" )`. `param=$@` isn't a well-defined operation, since it squashes content into a less-expressive form.

Comment: Nice you have put an example.

Comment: Given that the OP is trying to use `params=$@`, I'd say it's worth mentioning the correct way to do it in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than storing your args in `$params`, store all values in args, for example:

```
elif [ $# -eq 1 ] && [ "$1" = all ]; then
    set -- one two three four five
    # ^ this modifies argv ($@)
fi
```

Then, you don't have to use bash arrays, you can simply iterate with:

```
for param in "$@"; do
```

Often, bash-only features are used (called *bashisms*), while they may be unnecessary and less portable.

Another thing, replace the big ifelse with a case:

```
case "$param" in
    one)
        echo one
        ;; # equivalent of "break"
    two)
        echo two
        ;;
    *)
        echo default case
        ;;
esac
```

Comment: `-a` is actually deprecated (marked with `[OB]`, for obsolescent; see the POSIX spec for test at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html). Also, quote your expansions: `[ #@ -eq 1 ] && [ "$1" = all ]`; the string literal doesn't need quotes, the expansion does. Or you can use `[[ ]]` instead if the script has a ksh or bash shebang, and thus get to use `&&` internally and be able to skip the quotes on the left-hand side: [[ $# -eq 1 && $1 = all ]]`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy where does the link say it's deprecated?

Comment: Click on the `OB` next to the specification for `-a` for a definition of what that means.

Comment: thanks for the `-a` tip, but I prefer avoiding bashisms when possible so I avoid the "[["

Comment: Understood; do as you will there. Personally, I'm a fan of the ksh extensions later adopted by bash (the most important ones aren't actually *bashisms* as such but precede it), inasmuch as they're often useful to writing correct code (I mean, POSIX sh doesn't even have `local`! It doesn't have a `-d` argument to `read`, so you can't work with NUL-delimited streams; it doesn't have any `xargs` support for treating stdin as literal content; it doesn't have any number of things that are often *essential* to handling corner cases robustly. I do value portability, but value correctness more).

Comment: I agree that `sh` is quite plain and lacks a lot of stuff, but in the cases where I'm limited, my preference is to use a more powerful tool, like awk or python. Sometimes it even gets more readable :)